# What is the `uIdSubclass` in the third `SetWindowSubclass` Parameter?

Tags: c++, winapi

According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102(v=vs.85).aspx

the SetWindowSubclass prototype is:

```
BOOL SetWindowSubclass(
   __in  HWND hWnd,
   __in  SUBCLASSPROC pfnSubclass,
   __in  UINT_PTR uIdSubclass,
   __in  DWORD_PTR dwRefData
);
```

Ok, I understand `hWnd`, `pfnSubclass`, and `dwRefData`.

What I can not find good information on is, what do I set `uIdSubclass` to?

MSDN says:

> The subclass ID. This ID together with the subclass procedure uniquely identify
>   a subclass. To remove a subclass, pass the subclass procedure and this value to the
>   RemoveWindowSubclass function. This value is passed to the subclass procedure in the
>   uIdSubclass parameter.

Ok, understood, but still, where do I get this ID?  Is it something I create or do I get it someplace?  If it something I create, what should it look like?

I am doing this in C++ and Win32 API, nothing else.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm 90% sure, despite never hearing of the function, that it's an arbitrary number like the id you use to distinguish controls. This function makes me mad to see, though, after doing it the hard way. At least I know it exists now :)

Comment: I am just guessing here, but it seems that you are supposed to assign those ID's yourself. Since it is used in conjuction with subclass procedure to identify subclass, there is little space for collisions, and allows you to use the same function for several subclasses (eg. dispatcher functions). If you don't care, just use zero ;)

Comment: @j_kubik, "If you don't care, just use zero." That does seem to be the recurring trend of the winapi. "I don't know what to put. Oh well, guess I'll just pass 0." -works perfectly-

Comment: @chris So true,,, Anyway, 0 is usually (although not here) just a way of saying "use default". If you have smart defaults, it works more or less as you want it. This trend of WinAPI is not that bad, I think.

Comment: It is also usefull to read community notes section on those MSDN articles. Ususally they contain many information about gotchas that aren't clearly explained in the article itself.

Comment: It would be also interesting to check if this function is actually doing anyhthing more than just hiding how it's done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#winproc_subclassing

Comment: @j_kubik, Indeed, I don't mind it at all. It's a shame they didn't have some nice shiny C++ features to clean it up a little, though. I definitely agree with reading the bottom, as some articles have blatant mistakes, unmentioned problems, etc. About the link, that's what a lot of functions do, but it certainly makes it easier to use. Take `SetWindowText` vs. sending a `WM_SETTEXT`. It might not be the best example because of subtle differences (your window vs. someone else's window), but the point comes across.

Comment: Read carefuly Remarks in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This kind of "use for anything you want" parameter appears in several winapi functions.  Compare to CreateWindowEx(), last parameter for example.  General usage is to make the callback function operate on multiple objects.  But certainly a strong usage case is for C++, you can use it to store a pointer to a wrapper object.

Answer (score 0):

Karl E. Peterson writes about the purpose of the uIdSubclass parameter in Visual Studio Magazine 07/16/2009 [Subclassing the XP Way](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/07/16/subclassing-the-xp-way.aspx) and provides an example named [HookXP](https://classicvb.net/samples/HookXP/)

Topics discussed in Karl E. Peterson's article:

1. Use uIdSubclass to store a this pointer [or HWND].
2. Use dwRefData to pass optional data, e.g. pointer to create data.
3. It is important to handle WM_NCDESTROY in pfnSubclass and call
   RemoveWindowSubclass() passing uIdSubclass used in call to SetWindowSubclass().

Quotes from Karl E. Peterson's article

> Each subclass is identified two pieces of data along with the window's hWnd -- those being a pointer to the new message-handling procedure and a unique ID that's up to you to generate. You may also select to pass one Long value along as an extra parameter to each callback, for whatever purpose you may desire. The thought that immediately struck me was to use an ObjPtr() as the unique ID for each subclass. What object? The one that will be handling the callback!

> About the only undocumented caveat I've run into is that you must be sure to unhook your subclass before a window is destroyed. If you use my technique of embedding the handler in a form or class that's destroyed during the Form_Unload method, this should never be a problem. If you really don't want to take any chances, you can insert a simple branch in your handling routine:

```
   Select Case uiMsg
      Case WM_THIS
         '
      Case WM_THAT
         '
      Case WM_NCDESTROY
         Call Unhook  ' !!!
   End Select
```

The [Explorer Browser Search Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/samples-explorerbrowsersearch) also has a example of using uIdSubclass to store a pointer to this.

```
void CExplorerBrowserSearchApp::_OnInitializeDialog()
{
    ...
        // Register the searchbox icon to receive hover and mouseclick events
        SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(_hdlg, IDC_SEARCHIMG), s_SearchIconProc, (UINT_PTR)this, 0);
    ...
}
```

Raymond Chen's blog "The Old New Thing" article [Safer subclassing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883) also mentions the importance handling WM_NCDESTROY  in pfnSubclass for the purpose of calling RemoveWindowSubclass().

Quote from Raymond Chen's article

> One gotcha that isn’t explained clearly in the documentation is that you must remove your window subclass before the window being subclassed is destroyed. This is typically done either by removing the subclass once your temporary need has passed, or if you are installing a permanent subclass, by inserting a call to RemoveWindowSubclass inside the subclass procedure itself:

```
case WM_NCDESTROY:
  RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, thisfunctionname, uIdSubclass);
  return DefSubclassProc(...);
```

As a side note the Microsoft [SetWindowSubclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass#remarks) documentation has the caveat of SetWindowSubclass() being limited to a per thread basis.

> Warning  You cannot use the subclassing helper functions to subclass a window across threads.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have `ListViewHelper` C++ class that does something useful with `ListView` control. This class must subclass `ListView` and its parent (the dialog box, to receive notifications):

```cpp
// constructor
ListViewHelper(HWND hwndListView)
{
    SetWindowSubclass(hwndListView, listViewSubclassProc, 0,
        reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this)));
    SetWindowSubclass(GetParent(hwndListView), parentSubclassProc, 0,
        reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this)));
}
```

If dialog contains one `ListView` control, `uIdSubclass` does not needed and can be any number, usually 0.

But what if dialog contains two `ListView` controls? The second instance of `ListViewHelper` will call `SetWindowSubclass()` with the same arguments as the first instance, except for `dwRefData`, so `SetWindowSubclass()` will not subclass, but only change `dwRefData`. Oops, the first instance of `ListViewHelper` has stopped working.

In our case, we need to provide a different `uIdSubclass` to subclass the same window with the same `pfnSubclass`. You can use `this` or `hwndListView`:

```cpp
SetWindowSubclass(GetParent(hwndListView), parentSubclassProc,
    reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(hwndListView), reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this)));
```

I think there are other cases where `uIdSubclass` should be used.